# Changed File Asset & getting old version sometimes & new versions sometimes - cache has been cleared

Tags: community, libraries, guest-user, asset

I changed the image for a file asset.  I am sometimes getting the old image and sometimes getting the new image when I use the same URL.  It is as if Salesforce servers are out of sync.  Does anyone have experience with this problem & how long does it take to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days this problem resolved itself.  It seems like the asset files were likely cached on multiple Salesforce servers & it took time for everything to sync.  Salesforce technical support couldn't confirm this but had no other explanation.